# Is TestNg.xml file comes inbuilt with TestNg project. If yes, then I am not getting it

Tags: testng

Is Testng.xml file comes inbuilt with TestNg project. If yes, then I am not getting it. Please help! I have installed TestNg and trying to create a project but not able to found Testng.xml file in my project folders. I have tried to create multiple project, but no luck. Or either, I am getting lack somewhere.